# How do I rewrite my nested CSS calc operation

Tags: css, css-calc

How do I rewrite

```
margin: 15px calc(-100vw / 2 + 1009px / 2); // 1024px -15px padding
```

Now I have to write all my media queries and specify exact width, minus 15px (in my case) to get it working.

Instead of `1009px / 2` can I use another `calc()` here, like `(calc(100vw - 15px)) / 2`?

Comment: Why not just use those values directly in the calculation you're already performing, why do you think you need to wrap them in the `calc()` function again?

Comment: why not trying and see? the best reply you will get to your answer is to try your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested `calc` is fine, but [note that is not supported in IE11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()).  Also, you need to maintain the spacing convention:

```css
p {
  padding: calc(calc(5px + 5px) + calc(5px + 5px));
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello! I have a padding of 20px!</p>
```